# Difference between the formualas

Tags: probability-theory, game-theory, economics

What is the difference between the following formualas of the expected payoff $G$?

$$G_i(q|t_i)=\sum_{t_{-i}}p(t_{-i}|t_i)\sum_{a}q(a|t_{i},t_{-i})g_i((t_{i},t_{-i}),a)$$

and

$$G_i(q|t_i)=\sum_{t_{-i},a}p(t_{-i}|t_i)q(a|t_{i},t_{-i})g_i((t_{i},t_{-i}),a)$$

where $t_i$ is the type (or signal) of player $i$, $a=(a_i,a_{-i})$ the profile of actions and $g_i$ is the utility function

Comment: They look the same to me, given that the first probability seems to not depend on $a$.

Comment: and for me they seem to be the same, this is why I am asking. Maybe the author does this to emphasize what the first part of $\sum_{t_{-i}}p(t_{-i}|t_i)$ denotes